# Auto fill web page using ASP.Net C# web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I need to write a ASP.Net C# web page that can open a web page, fill in the fields and click the submit button on the web page automatically. My web page should launch the IE browser and navigate to a specified URL and fill the form and submit it. Not sure where I should start from. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that, browser will allow to run all your js code. 
But you can try with jquery, or with some another javascript lib.

You can add to your page **iframe** tag, than add dynamically another web-site to the iframe content. You also must know id's or classNames of html controls.

if you're going to use [jquery](http://jquery.com/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#textbox1').val()="someText1";
        ....
        $('#textboxN').val()="someTextN";


        //call click event
        $('#btnID').click();

 });
```

to automatically start your page, you can use [Process.Start() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28VS.71%29.aspx) in server side. 
if you're trying too run in client side, you can use [Response.Redirect Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a POST/GET call directly?

You could use HTTPWebRequest
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/HttpWebRequest_Response.aspx